Getting "An error occurred: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1006)" while running a Streamlit application
I am coding a Streamlit chatbot on VSCode using Python. I am using a corporate computer on a corporate network to code this, and there are a lot of security restrictions. When I do the command "streamlit run chatbot.py", it opens up the local host (it automatically assigned it as  http://localhost:8501) in Chrome, and the Streamlit application shows up. However, whenever I input any question into the ask bar, the bot returns me this error: "An error occurred: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1006)"
I have looked up different responses for this online, but I'm not really sure how to fix this; I'm pretty new to Streamlit and working on corporate networks. I have  TLS 1.3.
